Cover the 7x7 square with the 12 L-shaped pieces
Cover the 7x7 square on the left with the 12 L-shaped pieces on the right. You are not allowed to turn over any of the pieces, but you may rotate them in the plane.

Attribution:  Nob Yoshigahara

Here goes

 
    . . a a a . .
    . . a b b . .
    . . c c b . .
    . . d c b . .
    d d d c X e e
    Y X X X X f e
    Y Y Y f f f e
 

Two 2x4 rectangles were left out to make the rest more readable. The two exceptional pieces are X and Y.
Same solution, but in color:

 


I have added a picture, I think that makes your solution more clear.

Did you use some elimination logic? If so can you add explanation to answer? like for example : rot13(vs bar pbybef fdhner gvyrf purff nyvxr oynpx naq juvgr jvgu sbhe pbearef juvgr, gura Y-cragbzvab pbeare zhfg or ba n oynpx gvyr),

Thanks, @Lezzup, appreciate it.

@FirstNameLastName The only constraint I used is the one you mention.
